# Need Http Request not to respond until it finds a specific text in Jmeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, load-testing, stress-testing

I have searched for the solution to my problem throughout the web, but couldn't find any.

I need jmeter not to throw a response of an HTTP Request until it founds an specific text in response, because I have this request which takes so much time to respond and generate an specific text, but http request responds back immediately hence not find that specific text.

How to do it? should I use some kind of logic controller, which one and how?

As I am new to Jmeter so I need a proper guidance and solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is wait for a page change that will display the expected text, then this might be the answer otherwise try to clarify:

- http://www.sourcepole.ch/2011/1/4/waiting-for-a-page-change-in-jmeter

Comment: I have seen that example and implemented, it works but somehow loop doesn't work properly ... I wrote this in condition "${_javaScript("${DONE}" != "Resolved and Downloaded";)}" .... even though DONE changes it's value from "NOTHING" to "Resolved and Downloaded" but loop never stops/quit. what did I do wrong?

Comment: I tried with ${__javaScript("${DONE}" != "Resolved and Downloaded")} and it works for me. Add a Debug Sampler to see if DONE variable exists and has the value you think it has

Comment: yes there is a debug sampler, that's how I am sure that "DONE" exists and Changes its value.

Comment: Did you try my syntax ?, in yours you have _javascript, in mine the are 2 underscore

Comment: I have asked it as a separate question, please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069529/regular-expression-in-while-controller-jmeter/14070228#14070228

Comment: I have upvoted your answer but unfortunately it didn't resolve the issue instead started throwing exceptions so I can't mark it accepted.But yes it helped a lot. Cheers! :)

Comment: I answered to you in the Bugzilla you opened https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54362 .