# Regular expression in While Controller Jmeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, load-testing, stress-testing

I am using While Controller with Condition:

```
${_javaScript("${DONE}" ! = "Resolved and Downloaded";)}
```

where initially `DONE="Not Assigned yet"`.

After few iterations `DONE` changes and has value `Resolved and Downloaded` (which I check in Debug Sampler) but loop continues and doesn't quit.

What did I do wrong,What should I do to make it work?

Comment: [Got the answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 0):

Check syntax of your condition expression first: should be double `__` before function name and `,` instead of `;` after condition in function's params list:

```
${__javaScript("${DONE}"!="Resolved and Downloaded",)}
```

This can break your test case.
As well you can look into jmeter.log for possible issue details.

Comment: It's easier to look into log viewer

Comment: I tried but it didn't work .. In .log it is giving this exception...  ERROR - jmeter.functions.JavaScript: Error processing Javascript: ["Nothing Assigned Yet" ! = "Resolved and Risk Data Downloaded" ]
 org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: missing ; before statement (<cmd>#1)

Comment: I also tried with all the spaces removed after seeing this http://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/ErrorMessages ..but still getting error.

Comment: O, really? And what about double "__" before function name? Or is it conventionality?

Comment: I did not try with single "_" so can't say anything..but i think it is mandatory because I researched a lot, like crazy, past few days and I never saw anyone using it singly like "_"

Answer (score 0):

${__javaScript("${DONE}"!="Resolved and Downloaded")}

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following using while controller:

${__javaScript(${DONE} !="Resolved and Downloaded")}

Answer (score 0):

You may use if controller.Keeping the if controller as a child of runtime controller.Specify max time in runtime controller.

Under If controller specify the following:
"${DONE}" !="Resolved and Downloaded"